# Error: Redis connection to 0.0.0.0:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:6379

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose, node-redis

I have been trying to build the classical voting app. But my redis and mongodb are giving same error. I have to connect my redis to my node app and i have tried the following:

```
//redis
const redisoption = {
    host: "redis",
    port: 6379
};
```

.

```
//redis
const redisoption = {
    host: "0.0.0.0",
    port: 6379
};
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
```

services:

```
vote:
    image: adityagaddhyan/voting-app
    ports: 
        - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
        - redis
    networks:
        - front-end
        - back-end
    volumes: 
        - ./vote:/app
result:
    image: adityagaddhyan/voting-result
    ports: 
        - "3011:3011"
    depends_on:
        - mongodb
    networks: 
        - back-end
        - front-end
    volumes: 
        - ./result:/app

worker:
    image: adityagaddhyan/service-worker
    depends_on: 
        - redis
        - mongodb
    networks: 
        - back-end
    volumes: 
        - ./worker:/app
redis:
    image : redis
    command: ["redis-server", "--bind", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "6379"
    ports: 
        - "6379:6379"
    networks: 
        - back-end
    volumes: 
        - ./redis:/app
mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
        - "27017:27017"
    volumes: 
        - ./db:/app
```

volumes:
db-data:

networks:
front-end:
back-end:

I have tried all sort of combination.
I am majorily getting two kind of error.
if i use `host: "0.0.0.0",` i get

```
    Error: Redis connection to 0.0.0.0:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:6379
vote_1     |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16)
vote_1     | Emitted 'error' event on RedisClient instance at:
vote_1     |     at RedisClient.on_error (/usr/src/app/node_modules/redis/index.js:341:14)
vote_1     |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/redis/index.js:222:14)
vote_1     |     at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
vote_1     |     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
vote_1     |     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
vote_1     |     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
vote_1     |   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
vote_1     |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
vote_1     |   syscall: 'connect',
vote_1     |   address: '0.0.0.0',
vote_1     |   port: 6379
vote_1     | }
```

and if i use `host:redis`, i get:

```
    Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
worker_1   |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16)
worker_1   | Emitted 'error' event on RedisClient instance at:
worker_1   |     at RedisClient.on_error (/usr/src/app2/node_modules/redis/index.js:341:14)
worker_1   |     at Socket.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app2/node_modules/redis/index.js:222:14)
worker_1   |     at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
worker_1   |     at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
worker_1   |     at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
worker_1   |     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
worker_1   |   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
worker_1   |   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
worker_1   |   syscall: 'connect',
worker_1   |   address: '127.0.0.1',
worker_1   |   port: 6379
worker_1   | }
vote_1     | /usr/src/app/app.js:28
vote_1     |     host: back-end,
vote_1     |           ^
```

I am new to docker and unable to solve this problem. please help.

Comment: The host name `redis` should resolve to the Docker-internal address of the container, which should never be 127.0.0.1.  The error you're getting is from a separate `worker` container; can you show its configuration?  (`redis` should work, 0.0.0.0 doesn't make sense here.)

Comment: The part where 'redis' resolves to 127.0.0.1 makes me think something weird is going on with your docker networks. How are "back-end" and "front-end" setup?

Comment: actually i am getting the error in vote_1 too.. the same error. https://github.com/Adityagaddhyan/docker-voting-app chekc the src code here